# Can factor analysis be fit with gradient-based methods?

Tags: factor-analysis, gradient-descent

I know you can fit factor analysis [using EM](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/tr-96-1.pdf), but can you use gradient-based methods? If so, a reference would be great; otherwise, why not?